# RowselectionListener

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have a query about PrimeFaces. Is it possible to implement a RowSelectionListener component that is similar to

> `<h:commandLink value ="selection"
>   action="#{usuariosGruposBean.selectionOfGroupObject}"> 
>   <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{usuariosGruposBean.grps}"
>   value="#{groups}"/>  </h:commandLink>`

within a datatable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean for a datatable right ?

if so yes it's possible to do that, you just need to create a method like this

```
public void onEditRow(RowEditEvent event) {
enter code here
}
```

and register it in the JSF using something like this inside the DataTable tag

```
<p:ajax event="rowEdit" update="@this" listener="#{userController.onEditRow}" />
```

here it will update the whole Datatable because of the @this, if you want to update just a few column you could change that to the name of those columns separated by a space

which would look something like this

```
 <p:dataTable var="user" value="#{userController.allUsers}" id="userTable">                                
  <p:ajax event="rowEdit" update="@this" listener="#{userController.onEditRow}" /> 

   things inside the table

</p:datatable>
```

Comment: Glad I could help... also do what @flash said and get a look at the primefaces showcase, it's great and have a lot of code examples. but this one is not there because it's related to Primefaces 3 and the show case is for 2, the showcase for 3 is still being done.

Comment: @cfontes the showcase I linked is for primefaces 3 and always represents the latest trunk. I think it's deployed nightly or something like that.

Comment: Oh sorry I was not saying your link was wrong, sorry. Just pointing that the official show case doesn't have this solution as an example.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what you're trying to do, but have you looked at the [primefaces showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/datatableRowSelectionMultiple.jsf) yet? They have a lot of examples how to build a row selection listener.